# How to change all images url on webstory detail page in wordpress web story plugin using custom code?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

$story->load_from_post( $current_post );
$posterportrait = $story->get_poster_portrait();

Can i change this poster portrait through code

I tried this but not working
$story->set_poster_portrait(str_replace("webstories","webstories/wp-content/uploads", $posterportrait));

I have used this plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/web-stories/

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method as `set_poster_portrait` on the Story model.

You can see this in the source code https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/web-stories/trunk/includes/Model/Story.php#L173.

The poster is dynamically loaded from either the post thumbnail or the post meta by `Story_Post_Type::POSTER_META_KEY` meta key.

You can use the `get_{$meta_type}_metadata` filter for the latter, and the `post_thumbnail_id` filter for the former to dynamically replace the data.

If you want to replace the values in the database for good, you can update the post meta or the post thumbnail there using `update_post_meta` or `wp_update_post` as needed.